# Are operations before Thread.start() thread safe in relation to the new thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, happens-before, memory-visibility

Are there any guarantees to the variable visibility and/or ordering of instructions before `Thread.start()` in relation to the starting of the new thread?

Specifically, in the minimalistic example below, am I correct in assuming that `var` should be `volatile` in order for the output to be deterministic and always print "var = 10"?

```
public class ThreadExample {

    private int var;

    void example() {
        var = 10;
        Thread thread = new MyThread();
        thread.start();
    }

    class MyThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("var = " + var);
        }
    }

}
```

Note: My question only applies to the "new" Java memory model introduced in Java 5

Comment: JLS [§17.4.4. Synchronization Order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4): "An action that starts a thread *synchronizes-with* the first action in the thread it starts."

Comment: More specifically: JLS [§17.4.5. Happens-before Order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5): "A call to `start()` on a thread *happens-before* any actions in the started thread." So no, you do not need to make it `volatile`.